# replace value in multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

Here is my dataframe:

```
ID <- 1:4
var1 <- c("yes","no","yes","no")
var2 <- c("no","no","yes","no")
var3 <- c("yes","yes","no","no")
data <- data.frame(ID, var1, var2, var3)
```

I want to replace all of the `yes` by `1` and `no` by `0` in order to have such a table below

```
  ID var1 var2 var3
1  1    1    0    1
2  2    0    0    1
3  3    1    1    0
4  4    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be `across()` from `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
ID<-1:4
var1<-c("yes","no","yes","no")
var2<-c("no","no","yes","no")
var3<-c("yes","yes","no","no")
#Code
data<-data.frame(ID,var1,var2,var3,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Solution
data %>%
  mutate(across(c(var1:var3), ~ ifelse(.=='yes', 1, 0)))
```

Output:

```
  ID var1 var2 var3
1  1    1    0    1
2  2    0    0    1
3  3    1    1    0
4  4    0    0    0
```

And a `base R` solution would be using indexing with the values yes/no:

```
#Solution 2
data[data=='yes']<-1
data[data=='no']<-0
data[,-1] <- sapply(data[,-1],as.numeric)
```

Output:

```
  ID var1 var2 var3
1  1    1    0    1
2  2    0    0    1
3  3    1    1    0
4  4    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base` solution:

```
cbind(data[1], +(data[-1] == "yes"))

#   ID var1 var2 var3
# 1  1    1    0    1
# 2  2    0    0    1
# 3  3    1    1    0
# 4  4    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, (2:4) :=  lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(x == 'yes')), .SDcols = 2:4]
```